# Circular reference: Class has no constructors and the null member shared_ptr value

Tags: c++

I'd like to do this but I have an error that says `Y class has no constructors`

```
class Y;
class X
{
    std::shared_ptr<Y> base;
    //other  private stuff
public:
    X()
    {
        base = std::shared_ptr<Y>(new Y(this));
    }
    std::shared_ptr<Y> Get(){ return base; }
};
class Y
{
    X d;
    //other private stuff
public:
    Y(X * b) :d(*b){}
};
```

Use it as

```
X x; // all values in X is defined
std::shared_ptr<Y> spy=x.Get();
```

`spy` contains all private values in X except the shared_ptr of itself, which is  empty. Is this normal ?

More explanation: 
`spy` contains `d` that is `X`'s. If I view `d` inside `spy` in the debugger I see `base` is empty. Am only I wrong about this ?

Comment: Move the implementation of X below the declaration of Y.

Comment: Define `X::X` out of class, after the definition of `Y`.

Comment: How about `spy`'s containing values as I see in debugger ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the definition of `X::X()` depends on the the existence of a specific `Y` constructor, it needs to come after the latter. That is:

```
class Y;

class X
{
    std::shared_ptr<Y> base;
    //other  private stuff
public:
    X(); // just the declaration here, we don't know that Y(X*) is 
         // a valid constructor yet. 
    std::shared_ptr<Y> Get(){ return base; }
};

class Y
{
    /* all of Y */
};

// NOW, this is valid
// because we know that Y::Y(X*) is a valid constructor
X::X() {
    base = std::shared_ptr<Y>(new Y(this));
}
```

Comment: Why hasn't this ever been an issue in other languages like Java or C# ?

Comment: @DavidCattor C++ isn't Java or C#. They have different rules.

Comment: @DavidCattor Because different languages have different rules. In C++ order matters.

Comment: Supposing that `X` and `Y` are in different files, how does the move become effective as said ?

Comment: @DavidCattor You'd put the `X` constructor into `X.cpp` and have it include `Y.h`.

Comment: How about my second question ?

Comment: @DavidCattor At the time you call `new Y(this)`, `base` doesn't point to anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is `new Y(this)` is should be placed in a scope where Y  is completely defined, not only declared.